# Deprecation warning `the server/replset/mongos/db options are deprecated` is showing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how to remove this warnings, after connecting to mongo using mongoose 5.2.17 with options server.ssl is enabled.

> the server/replset/mongos/db options are deprecated, all their options
>   are supported at the top level of the options object
>   [poolSize,ssl,sslValidate,sslCA,sslCert,sslKey,sslPass,sslCRL,autoReconnect,noDelay,keepAlive,keepAliveInitialDelay,connectTimeoutMS,family,socketTimeoutMS,reconnectTries,reconnectInterval,ha,haInterval,replicaSet,secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS,acceptableLatencyMS,connectWithNoPrimary,authSource,w,wtimeout,j,forceServerObjectId,serializeFunctions,ignoreUndefined,raw,bufferMaxEntries,readPreference,pkFactory,promiseLibrary,readConcern,maxStalenessSeconds,loggerLevel,logger,promoteValues,promoteBuffers,promoteLongs,domainsEnabled,checkServerIdentity,validateOptions,appname,auth,user,password,authMechanism,compression,fsync,readPreferenceTags,numberOfRetries,auto_reconnect,minSize,monitorCommands,retryWrites,useNewUrlParser]

Comment: Can you add relevant pieces of the code what you are doing?

Comment: This answer has solved the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540379/3999660

Answer (score 12):

From the warning message what I found out is well documented [here.](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5442#issuecomment-314199168)

It says, **move the settings from the `server`, `replset`, and `mongos` keys up into the top level of the object**.

```
// The options inside the `server` attributes are moved to its parents.
// Same happens to `replset` and `mongos`
// Change this
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/db',
  {
    useMongoClient: true,
    server: {
      poolSize: 2
    },
    promiseLibrary: global.Promise
  }
);

// To this
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/db',
  {
    useMongoClient: true,
    poolSize: 2,
    promiseLibrary: global.Promise
  }
);
```

For more information refer [options in mongoose docs.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options)

Comment: Any idea if I'm getting this warning, does that mean that my options are not getting applied? Let's say I have increased the reconnectTries and reconnectInterval(by the old method of keeping it in the server object), then is it possible that it's actually not getting applied and taking the default values?